# php hash() with sha512 showing different results for same value

Tags: php, hash, sha512

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$xmlfile='xml/adminpwd.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);

if (!empty($_POST['password'])) {
    extract($_POST);
    if($adminpwd!='this')
        $error="Incorrect Password. Enter the correct password.";
}
?>

<form method='post' action='' name='admin'>
<h3 style="color: #798196;">Enter Current Password</h3><br/>
        <input type='password' name='adminpwd' />
        <input type='submit' name='password' value='Enter'>
</form>
```

this is my script.

when i try this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($error))
        echo "<br/><h3 class='error'>".hash('sha512', $adminpwd)."</h3><br/>";
?>
```

i get output:
*de784a6d81e125ff2223d977683c3efdd4513941d3737861008b8358d10e8d2757963c3a2619d0924a70d0e11b53492847f741af6e767388fd395c170508d795*

but when i try this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($error))
        echo "<br/><h3 class='error'>".hash('sha512', $_POST['adminpwd'])."</h3><br/>";
?>
```

i get output:
*1fc286c9c7dc733b3a46a21a923c646c14c19bac951d63380ec8d4b3c6786fdbe7dd4bd325eef31553fa829e19989fe060da01921cfc68f7b9ff03383f78710b*

though both variable contains same string. why the output differs?

Comment: Just print out `$adminpwd` in both cases. You don't *know* they're the same until you see both of them. Note also that leading/trailing whitespace is always suspect as well.

Comment: Good point here ↑↑↑ make sure to trim the entered text.

Comment: both time i was entering the same password. and repeated the experiment more than 5 times to confirm. but the result was same.

when i tried now, both cases giving same output. didn't get the problem. but thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is wrongly tested.

Answer (score 3):

The only way for it to be different is if what's in $_POST['adminpwd'] is not the exact same string value. It's possible that since you aren't checking $adminpwd, that maybe it wasn't being set every time.

Also, using extract() on $_POST or any other request variables is not terribly safe, as you're essentially allowing users to create PHP variables.